# how to have the shadow of a lightshade on surrounding walls in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have created a scene with a light shade, walls surrounding it, and few light sources. I want the spotlights inside the lamp shade cast shadow on the walls.I played with parameters of the spotlight, but I could not achieve having shadow on the walls. here is my code:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Lightshade</title>


<script src="three.js"> </script>
<script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<script>

//declaring variables
var camera, scene, renderer;
var controls;
var cone, coneGeometry;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -window.innerWidth /  25, window.innerWidth / 25, window.innerHeight / 25, -window.innerHeight /  25, -10000, 1000000);

camera.position.set( 0, 2.0, 5.0);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);  

//adding the renderer to the screen
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xeeeeee , 0); //eeeeee
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//adding the camera interactive method
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.noKeys = true;


//creating materials for lightshade
BlightshadeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffeb00,wireframe:false, side:THREE.DoubleSide, ambient: 0xffffff});
lightshadeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:0xffeb00,transparent: true,opacity: 0.6,wireframe:false, side:THREE.DoubleSide, ambient: 0xffffff});




// adding some light to the screen
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100); 
light3.position.set( 0, 30.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light3 );        

var light1 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff,0.7, 100  ); 
light1.position.set( 0, 4.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light1 );
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.7, 100  ); 
light2.position.set( 0, -1.0, 0 ); 
scene.add( light2 );

var light4 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100); 
light4.position.set( 30.0, 16.0, 30.0 ); 
scene.add( light4 );

var light5 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100); 
light5.position.set( -30.0, 16.0, 30.0 ); 
scene.add( light5 );

coneGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 12.5, 15.0, 30, 20 , true);
cone = new THREE.Mesh(coneGeometry,lightshadeMaterial);
cone.castShadow = true;
scene.add(cone);

innerConeGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 4.5, 12.0, 15.0, 30,20 , true);
innerCone = new THREE.Mesh(innerConeGeometry,lightshadeMaterial);
innerCone.castShadow = true;
scene.add(innerCone);


upGeometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 4.5, 5.0, 30 ,3 );
upSide = new THREE.Mesh( upGeometry, BlightshadeMaterial );
scene.add( upSide );
upSide.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI/2));
upSide.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0,7.5,0)); 

downGeometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 12.0, 12.5, 30 ,3 );
downSide = new THREE.Mesh( downGeometry, BlightshadeMaterial );
scene.add( downSide );
downSide.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(Math.PI/2));
downSide.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0,-7.5,0));


//Creating the shadow

var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00 } ));
point.position.set(0,2.5,-1.0);
scene.add( point );
var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff ,3, 800    , Math.PI/4);

spotlight.target = point;
//to cast the light horizontally to the light shade
spotlight.position.set(0,2.5,0);
spotlight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
// must enable shadow casting ability for the light
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 512; 
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 512;

spotlight.shadowCameraFov = 300;
scene.add(spotlight);
var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ));
point.position.set(1.0,2.5,0);
scene.add( point );
var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff ,3, 800, Math.PI/4);

spotlight.target = point;
//to cast the light horizontally to the light shade
spotlight.position.set(0,2.5,0);
spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
// must enable shadow casting ability for the light

spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 512; 
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 512;

spotlight.shadowCameraFov = 30.0;
scene.add(spotlight);
var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ));
point.position.set(-1.0,2.5,0);
scene.add( point );
var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff ,3, 800, Math.PI/4);

spotlight.target = point;
//to cast the light horizontally to the light shade
spotlight.position.set(0,2.5,0);
spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
// must enable shadow casting ability for the light
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 512; 
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 512;
spotlight.shadowCameraFov = 30.0;
scene.add(spotlight);
var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ));
point.position.set(1.0,2.5,-1.0);
scene.add( point );
var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff ,3, 800, Math.PI/4);

spotlight.target = point;
//to cast the light horizontally to the light shade
spotlight.position.set(0,2.5,0);

spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
// must enable shadow casting ability for the light
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 512; 
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 512;

spotlight.shadowCameraFov = 300;
scene.add(spotlight);
var point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ));
point.position.set(-1.0,2.5,-1.0);
scene.add( point );
var spotlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff ,3, 800, Math.PI/4);

spotlight.target = point;
//to cast the light horizontally to the light shade
spotlight.position.set(0,2.5,0);

spotlight.shadowDarkness = 0.95;
// must enable shadow casting ability for the light
spotlight.castShadow = true;
spotlight.shadowMapWidth = 512; 
spotlight.shadowMapHeight = 512;

spotlight.shadowCameraFov = 30.0;
scene.add(spotlight);
//create walls and floor
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(170, 170, 100, 100);
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
floor.position.y = -70;

// Note the mesh is flagged to receive shadows
floor.castShadow= false;
floor.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(floor);

//front wall
var frontMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var frontGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(170, 100, 100, 100);
var front = new THREE.Mesh(frontGeometry, frontMaterial);
front.position.z = -85;
front.position.y = -20;
//front.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
// Note the mesh is flagged to receive shadows
front.castShadow= false;
front.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(front);

//right wall
var rightMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var rightGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(170, 100, 100, 100);
var right = new THREE.Mesh(rightGeometry, rightMaterial);
right.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
right.position.x = 85;
right.position.y = -20;

// Note the mesh is flagged to receive shadows
right.castShadow= false;
right.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(right);

//left wall
var leftMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var leftGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(170, 100, 100, 100);
var left = new THREE.Mesh(leftGeometry, leftMaterial);
left.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;
left.position.x = -85;
left.position.y = -20;
// Note the mesh is flagged to receive shadows
left.castShadow= false;
left.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(left);



function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

render();
}

function render() {


controls.update();

renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();



</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, do you know any other better way to have the shadow of the light shade on the walls. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems similar to an issue I had: [Three.js DoubleSided material doesn't cast shadow on both sides of planar parametric geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463247/three-js-doublesided-material-doesnt-cast-shadow-on-both-sides-of-planar-parame)

In particular, "The material.side property is not taken into consideration when casting shadows."